# Contraction between metric tensor and non-tensor entity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, acceleration

In general relativity, I know that
$$u^\mu=\dfrac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}$$
and
$$a^\mu=\dfrac{d u^\mu}{d \tau}$$
where spacetime coordinates of a particle are a function of proper time
and they are not tensors because they are calculated by ordinary derivative instead of covariant derivative so, I can't lower or raise indices by metric tensor but can I contract two of them with metric tensor as the following?
$$a^2= g_{\mu \nu} a^\mu a^\nu$$
and what is the meaning of u and a? are they still velocity and acceleration? and what is the difference between them and others calculated by covariant derivative? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $s$ in the first two equations a parameter along a curve? If so shouldn't the formulas be total derivatives rather than partial derivatives?

Comment: $$\partial s$$ represents the line element.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: Let me ask a different question, what is $x^\mu$? What is it a function of?

Comment: $$x^\mu$$ is the space-time coordinates of a particle and derivative with respect to line element or we can sure replace it by the proper time of the particle. Coordinates of the particle are a function of the line element or proper time.

Comment: So $x^\mu$ is in fact a curve parameterized by $s$ (and only $s$). Consequently, derivatives with respect to $s$ are total derivatives.

Comment: It also it means that both $u^\mu$ and $a^\mu$ are in fact contravariant vectors (but not vector fields), and therefore tensors (but not tensor fields).

Comment: Great, but I don't understand how they can be tensors without using affine connection in the derivative?

Comment: Sorry actually only $u^\mu$ is a tensor, $a^\mu$ of course is not.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: This question could be improved by editing it to include the clarifications made in the comments.

Comment: Okay, @PaulT. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally one writes $\big(x^0(\tau),x^1(\tau),x^2(\tau),x^3(\tau)\big)$ for the worldline of a massive particle parameterized by its proper time $\tau$.  In this case, the 4-velocity $\mathbf u(\tau)$ with components $u^\mu =\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ is a 4-vector.

Partial derivatives only make sense when a quantity is a function of more than one variable, which is not the case here.  $x^\mu$ is a function *only* of the proper time $\tau$, and so an ordinary derivative is appropriate. Furthermore, $\mathbf u(\tau)$ is the normalized tangent vector to the worldline, and so you can raise and lower its indices or contract it with tensorial quantities however you wish.

The 4-acceleration $\mathbf A(t)$ is a bit more subtle. Being more explicit with the definition of the 4-velocity, we have that
$$u^\mu(\tau) := \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^\mu(\tau+\epsilon)-x^\mu(\tau)}{\epsilon}$$
As you can see, $u^\mu$ is computed by subtracting the coordinates $x^\mu$ at different values of $\tau$; this is fine because the coordinates $x^\mu$ are scalar functions, so you're just subtracting numbers.  However, this no longer works for vectors; it doesn't make sense to subtract vectors which don't live at the same point, so the naive definition $A^\mu = \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}$ does not result in a tensor.

---

The technology one needs to compute the derivative of $\mathbf u(\tau)$ is a *parallel transporter* $\mathbb T$.  The transporter gives us a way to transport a vector $\mathbf V$ along a curve $\gamma$.  More concretely, let $\mathbf V$ be a vector attached to the point $\gamma(0)$; then the parallel transporter $\mathbb T_{\gamma}$ moves $\mathbf V$ by an infinitesimal parameter distance $\delta$ along the curve $\gamma$ as follows:

$$\tilde{\mathbf V} \equiv \mathbb T_\gamma[\mathbf V,\delta] := \left(\mathbb I - \delta \dot \gamma^\mu \Gamma_\mu\right) \mathbf V$$

where for each $\mu$, $\Gamma_\mu$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix. In component form, this becomes

$$\tilde V^\alpha = V^\alpha  - \delta \dot \gamma^\mu \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu \beta} V^\beta$$

With this technology in hand, we can properly define the derivative of the 4-velocity:

$$\mathbf A := \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb T_x[\mathbf u(\tau+\epsilon),-\epsilon] - \mathbf u(\tau)}{\epsilon}$$

In words, one takes the vector $\mathbf u(\tau+\epsilon)$ (which is attached to the position $x^\mu(\tau+\epsilon)$), *transports it backward along $x^\mu$ by $\epsilon$*, and then subtracts $\mathbf u(\tau)$.  The result in component form is

$$A^\mu = \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} u^\alpha u^\beta \equiv \frac{Du^\mu}{d\tau}$$

where $a^\mu \equiv \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}$ - the derivatives of the *components* of $\mathbf u$ - is sometimes called the *coordinate acceleration*, and $\frac{Du^\mu}{d\tau}$ is a common shorthand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i need. thank you again. But the last question, $$\dfrac{D u^\mu}{d\tau}$$ is called proper acceleration?

Comment: @FadyTarek See e.g. [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration#Four-acceleration_in_non-inertial_coordinates).  The usual term for $\mathbf A$ is the 4-acceleration. It is apparently the consensus on wikipedia that the term "proper acceleration" should be reserved for the magnitude of $\mathbf A$ rather than $\mathbf A$ itself, but this convention is not universal and when in doubt, you should ask.